# Is "he could not remember how many" a noun phrase in 1984 by Orwell?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, literature

I'm reading 1984 lately.

I found the sentence below in it, and here's my question.

> Since then there had been other changes—two, three, he could not remember how many.

I think the phrase "he could not remember how many" is not a sentence, but a kind of number expression. I mean, it seems that it can be paraphrased as "... other chances―two, three, too many changes for him to remember."

If my sense is right, this type of English expression is a little bit tricky, but for example, *The Christmas Carol* by Dickens has the sentence below in its beginning.

> Scrooge and he[Marley] were partners for I don't know how many years.

In general, the preposition "for" can be accompanied only by a noun phrase(e.g. I have lived in Japan for many years.). In that logic, you have to interpret the Dickens' phrase "I don't know how many years" as a sort of noun expression, and indeed some advanced books for the Engish grammar claim that kind of expression exits.

I also think it is not wrong to interpret the Orwell's phrase as just a sentence, but my sense of English reading ability says it is more proper to regard it as a noun expression(number expression).

Please tell me what you think, and I'd be glad if you would answer my question.

Comment: Of course a phrase isn't a sentence. It's just a phrase implying 'so many that I/he can't remember the exact number'.

Comment: I'd say it's more like a "sentence" than a "noun". Orwell could just as well have written ***who knows**?* in that position, in which case I'd say it was a "question" rather than a noun. But honestly, I don't see how attempting to label "parts of speech" in such "stream of consciousness" contexts helps one learn English.